# Ping any domain is directed to 10.10.10.10

Tags: windows-10, dns, internet, ping

I have two windows 10 computers on my network. Connected via a wifi ap and the other Lan.
Occasionally they will loose internet access, and when I try to ping any domain, it always tries 10.10.10.10 until I restart the computer.

Running /ipconfig rlease,  renew, and flushdns, as well as disabling the adaptor doesn't work.
One computer has a manual dns server set to 1.1.1.1,1.0.0.1

The other devices on the network don't suffer this problem, but I have restarted the ap and router anyway.

What is going on, and how can I fix it without restarting the computer?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you manually set the DNS server to a known public DNS server, such as the one at 4.2.2.2 or the one at 8.8.8.8?

If that works well, then the issue was bad DNS settings.  This may often be caused by DHCP.  The best way to troubleshoot that further, if desired, may be to set the computer's "DNS server" settings back to automatic, and wait for the problem to occur again.  Then, when the problem does occur again, run "IPConfig /ALL" and look for a line (or multiple lines) saying "DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . :"

Then, the device at that IP address is likely the culprit of the problems.  Go to that address with HTTP (in other words, type that address into a web browser) and you'll often find the device identifies itself.

The cause is often a device, such as a wireless access point, that tries to automatically figure out what DNS information it should use, and having a problem with that.  Then, the device passes on that bad DNS information to other devices on your network.

The most ideal solution will be to fix the device, and the details on how to do that will depend on specific details like just what type of device is being used.  One way to try solving the problem, which is probably the best fix if this easy approach resolves the problem for you, might be just applying an available authentic firmware update.  Other solutions might involve improving the quality of the Internet connection that this device experiences.

An alternative solution, which is probably satisfying enough for most scenarios, may be to just go to that device's DHCP settings and tell it what DNS servers to hand out.  Instead of "automatically detected DNS servers", but in something reliable like 4.2.2.2 or 8.8.8.8 (and make sure that you successfully save your changes).  If a more satisfying solution (which actually fixes an identified problem) isn't found, this workaround is often an available approach which can work quite sufficiently well.

Comment: I have already tried manually setting the dns server to 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8. The access point is in forwarding mode. There is only one dhcp server on the network. Only a restart of the affected computer fixes the problem and all other devices can access the internet.

Comment: Also, make sure you are not just pinging domain names (DNS names), but also different IP addresses.  *When you are experiencing problems*, gather info and then report your private IP addresses (start with 192.168. or 10. or 172.16. or fe80: or fd) and the DHCP server reported by the Windows 10 computers, and results of pinging 8.8.8.8 and pinging the Default Gateway showing on the computesr with problems.

Comment: I get a normal response pinging the gateway and other hosts via ip. Are you asking if the computer is being assigned an ip from dhcp? Then yes. (192.168.0.x) I also tried setting a static ip on both the router and computer side.

Comment: I suspect I can crack this nut, but I need to get really specific. I don't mean to belittle, but I am starting to doubt if I will get this resolved while remaining somewhat vague. When the problem occurs, please run: `IPConfig.exe /ALL >> output-bad1.txt`.  Also, `ping -n 1 8.8.8.8 >> output-bad1.txt` and `tracert 8.8.8.8 >> output-bad1.txt`.  In the tracert results, replace the first public IP address (not starting with 10 or 192.168. or 172.16-172.31) with x's, and remove all later lines.  After rebooting & things work, repeat but use `outputok.txt` instead of `output-bad1.txt`

Comment: I didn't consider tracert. The problem is sporadic, so it might be some time before it happens again

Comment: It took a while for it to work again, the problem started persisting through reboots. I noticed that just pinging the 8.8.8.8 didn't show any problems (to me) so I also included results using google.com https://gist.github.com/grayatrox/ae87500e47c481a6e0ba16c1e3437c22

Comment: The problem with pinging google.com is that google.com is resolving to 10.10.10.10 (when problems occur). Most likely the fault of the DNS server located via IPv6 address fe80::1 so figure out what device uses that (by visiting that in a web browser, or if that doesn't work then use "`netsh int ipv6 show neigh`" and then do an OUI lookup on the first half of the MAC address), or just adjust your adapter's IPv6 settings so no IPv6 DNS servers are configured (instead use IPv4 static DNS (1.1.1.1 and/or 1.0.0.1 and/or 8.8.8.8 and/or 8.8.4.4 should work okay).  Disable DNS on that or restart it